# Default globalErrors in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, bean-validation

I want to know if there are any default globalErrors in Spring framework. I need to create my own custom validator by implementing `org.springframework.validation.Validator` interface. And there I add a `globalError` by `errors.reject()`.

In controller class I have to catch this custom validation error If it's occurred. My plan is to catch it by using `getGlobalErrors` method. But if there any default globalErrors in spring, they will be also caught by `getGlobalErrors` method.

So I really need to know if there are any default `globalErrors` in Spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I think there is just one type of errors - when object or some of its fields cannot be mapped to Java object.

For example - when you are trying to set null value from your front-end for LocalDateTime - it's gonna give you an error.

I really believe there are no other errors you can have.

Answer (score 0):

`getGlobalErrors` method is there in the Spring. Here is the URL -

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/AbstractBindingResult.html#getGlobalErrors()